# How to retrieve the current current texture used by an MTKView/UIView/NSView

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

I want to copy the screen of an MTKView (or an UIView or an NSView). How to retrieve the current drawable (or texture) actually used to draw to content of this MTKView? If I use currentDrawable then I retrieve a texture that is not actual (already too old)

Comment: Do you need texture before or after rendering?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 : after rendering :)

Answer (score 2):

You can register a completion handler:

```
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> cb) 
{
    id<MTLTexture> texture = view.currentDrawable.texture;
    /* ... */
}];
```

For better performance, release drawables as soon as possible.

Comment: Can I keep the texture as long as I want ? I mean the texture not the drawable

Comment: No, you should release a drawable (texture) as soon as possible.

Comment: if you want to save the texture copy it to another texture using [MTLBlitCommandEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder?language=objc)